# Task management tool that can link a task to specific part of code?

Tags: git, github, redmine, mantis

I'm looking for a task management tool that would allow me to do something that seems really obvious to me: link a task/issue to a specific part of my code (using Git).

Here is an example of what I'm expecting from this tool :

- I click on "new task"
- In the task creation, I can set the title, the description...AND the file/line in my current git repository.
- Once the task is created, I can see exactly where I have to look in my code to achieve it.

I watched Redmine, Mantis, Trac, etc.. but I'm not sure they can make it.
The answer is probably somewhere on Google but I'm not sure to use relevant keywords to find it :(
Note that I already use github.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code is in GitHub you can easily link directly to a line of code, e.g.

https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Makefile#L449

The easiest way to generate this link is to browse to the appropriate revision and file using the web interface and click in the margin on the line number you want to reference. Your address bar should update. Copy and paste.

Ranges are also supported:

https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Makefile#L451-L466

To generate these, click the first line number, then shift-click the second.

These links can be used in their own Issues system, or any other issue tracker that supports external HTML links.

If you want to *embed* code in your tickets, you could experiment with [gist-it](http://gist-it.appspot.com/).

Example:

```
<script src="http://gist-it.appspot.com/github/git/git/blob/master/Makefile?slice=451:466"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know about that. Could you be more specific on the HTML links external support from issues trackers? Does it mean that this would display the code in the issues tracker just be providing the github link?

Comment: It would just be a link. If you want to embed, you could use a service like [gist-it](http://gist-it.appspot.com/) to generate embeds for GitHub code. I've added an example to the answer.